# Sorting a 3D vector of pairs

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, std-pair

I have the following vector declared:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<float, int>>>> depth;
```

I want to sort the pairs in every vector in ascending order by their first element.

Sorting:

```
for(std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<float,int>>> vec1 : depth) {
    for(std::vector<std::pair<float,int>> vec2 : vec1) {
        std::sort(vec2.begin(), vec2.end());
    }
}
```

And then printing:

```
for (std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<float,int>>> vec1 : depth) {
    for (std::vector<std::pair<float, int>> vec2 : vec1) {
        if(!vec2.empty() && (vec2.size() > 1)) {
            for (std::pair<float, int> pr : vec2) {
                std::cout << pr.first << " " << pr.second << "   ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

A part of the result:

```
4.65514 1   3.10343 2   
4.67043 1   3.11362 2   
4.68594 1   3.12396 2
```

How it should be:

```
3.10343 2   4.65514 1
3.11362 2   4.67043 1
3.12396 2   4.68594 1
```

Any help is appreciated, as I really ran out of things to try to do and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You're sorting copies. Typo.

Comment: Sort using references `std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<float,int>>>& vec1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As LogiStuff said in the comments, you are sorting copies.  This is  because the way you use the for-range, having a iteration variable that is copy constructed from each element of the range.

To solve this, you just have to add an `&` to iterate over the range by reference, so that the vector is sorted in place.  Even better, use `auto` to move a step forward towards modern C++:

```
for(auto &vec1 : depth) {
  for(auto &vec2 : vec1) {
    std::sort(vec2.begin(), vec2.end());
    }
}
```

Here the [online demo](http://ideone.com/Gvgizt)